# Search company names in news using python

Tags: python, string-matching

I have a list of companies like the following

```
companies = [Advance Auto Parts Inc, AllianceBernstein Holding L.P., AbbVie Inc., Asbury Automotive Group Inc, ABM Industries Incorporated]
```

I also have daily news data.

```
News = ['news1', 'news2', 'news3']
```

Now I want to search these names in the news data but in News company names do not occur as complete names like in the list above. I want to do something like this:

```
for news in News:
    for company in companies:
        if (company in news): 
            print('do something')
```

The best idea right now comes to my mind is to take the names of all the companies in a way that are expected to be called in News but that will take a lot of time because I have thousands of companies.
Any suggestions to handle this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion that may help: try google alerts. I have one set for a few companies so that I'm more or less up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Try identifying the most common endings first; e.g. ***Inc*** or ***Ltd***, then you'll be able to search the news for ***Advance Auto Parts Inc*** and the stripped version ***Advance Auto Parts***. Then you could try to find out if there are any other words like ***Group*** or strings like ***And Sons*** in the name.

Every time run the news searching function with the whole name and then with each one of the stripped versions.

```
news(company_name):
    stripped_versions = company_name
    stripped_versions += strip(company_name)
    for version in stripped_versions:
        search_news(version)
```

Where stripped_versions is a list of the company's name including the stripped versions, for example: [Advance Auto Parts Inc, Advance Auto Parts]

I hope this pseudo-code helped you approach your problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to pick up company name lists from the internet itself and rebuild your list. Tweaking up google searches using google dorks might help you.

Like putting

```
list of fortune 500 companies ext:xls
```

The above dork in google search bar will pop up some xls file with the list . I think that will still require some manual work but at better ease